# Open all files in folder with JPG extension while scripting Photoshop

Tags: javascript, vbscript, photoshop-script

Does anyone know how one might open in Photoshop all files with a particular file extension rather than individual file names using VBScript? Alternatively, could I use a JS function to do this?

Comment: is this in WSH? or a browser? or some other environment?

Comment: Photoshop Scripting to be more specific

Comment: well, that is probably possible then, I'd add that important point in the question if I were you - but I don't know JS in PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, VBScript can be used to externally automate Photoshop, via the Windows Script Host.

> ## Targeting and Referencing the Application object
>
> Because you run your AppleScript and VBScript scripts from outside the Photoshop application, the first thing your script should do is indicate that the commands be executed in Photoshop

[Link to PDF, p. 22](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2015.pdf)

VBScript can access the **FileSystemObject** type, which is a part of the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** library. **FileSystemObject** allows you to iterate over each file in a folder and check the extension.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim app
Set app = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")

Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim fle
For Each fle In fso.GetFolder("c:\path\to\folder").Files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(fle.Path) = ".jpeg" Then

        'Issue the command to open the file in the default format
        'This uses the Open method from the Photoshop object model
        app.Open fle.Path

    End If
Next
```

References:

- [Microsoft Scripting Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/bstcxhf7(v%3dvs.84)) library, [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/6kxy1a51%28v%3dvs.84%29), [Folder object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/1c87day3%28v%3dvs.84%29)
- [Photoshop CC Scripting Guide 2015](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2015.pdf)

---

Note that the same code could be written in an externally controlling Javascript file:

```
var app = new ActiveXObject('Photoshop.Application');
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

var enumerator = new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder('c:\\path\\to\\folder').Files);
while (!enumerator.atEnd()) {
    var filepath = enumerator.item().Path;
    if (fso.GetExtensionName(filepath) == '.jpeg') {

        app.Open(filepath);

    }
    enumerator.moveNext();
}
```

but the examples in the Scripting Guide are using internally executing Javascript files; they must be saved in a specific folder, and can only be run once the application is open, and within the context of the application.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this helped alot and i've got it working now! :D

Comment: @NickCageWellfair If this information is _useful_ then upvore (with the up arrow next to the answer). If the information _answers your question_, then mark the answer with the green checkmark next to the answer. This helps the next person who runs into a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You can open any file

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""ENTER LOCATION""")
```

For a file extension try maybe changing the location to a search. For example, to search .jpg from my pc the location is

```
search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20This%20PC&crumb=fileextension%3A~<.jpg%20OR%20System.Generic.String%3A.jpg&crumb=location:%3A%3A{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

Don't open a popular extension in a drive or drive sub folder or your computer will crash. Ristrict your files into a folder with minimal subfolders and files.

You can open an application like that as well or you can you system32 in batch-file.
I am not sure if this is what you want answered as it is not clear.

Comment: Please vote if this what you want. If not comment what changes need to be made.